# Proving that if $A$ and $B$ are events, then $\Pr[A ∩ B] \ge \Pr[A] + \Pr[B] - 1$

Tags: probability, proof-verification

I am just looking for some guidance whether I am approaching the questions correctly. New to probability!

> Prove that if $A$ and $B$ are events, then $$\Pr[A \cap B] \geq \Pr[A]+\Pr[B]-1$$

I rewrote the statement in the following way :

$$1 \geq \Pr[A] + \Pr[B] - \Pr[A \cap B]$$

And based on some probability properties, I rewrote out the statement again:

$$1 \geq \Pr[A \cup B]$$

Is this enough to prove the statement?

Comment: Perfect!  ...      ...

Answer (score 1):

So you use $$P(A\cup B ) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$$ and that $P(A\cup B)\leq 1$

So you got $$1\geq  P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$$ and now swap $1$ and $P(A\cap B)$ and you got what you want.

That is correct.